# Sort Meteor Collection First By Specific Value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am building an application where I want to filter a returned collection based on a specific name, where the current `Meteor.user().username` always shows first in the returned list. I want to do something like this:

```
 Lists.find({}, {sort : {user: Meteor.user().username}});
```

Comment: You can sort the result only by a specific `field`, not by a value. Can you be more clear? Do you want to filter the documents for a specific user, and then sort by some field? Can you please include two sample documents and the desired output which depicts the problem.

Comment: @BatScream that was exactly what I needed to hear. Please see posted answer and give opinion.

Answer (score 1):

From input from @BatScream, I ended up doing two different querys. One where I looked for the specific username and a second where I looked for all others besides the user name. After I just combined the two querys.

```
 Lists.find({user: Meteor.user().username});

 &&

 Lists.find({user: {$ne : Meteor.user().username});
```

Comment: So how is this different from - `Lists.find({})`. The first query returns documents for specific user, the second one - for all the other users. When you do a union(correct me if i am wrong), you get all the documents in the collection. Can you please be more clear on what your intention is?

Comment: @BatScream, the second `find` should sort its result by the username `field`.

Comment: @BatScream, I am returning the entire collection, however I am ensuring that the first items in the collection's array are always specific to the user. I am doing this just to add ease and clarity to the ui.

Comment: You can get all the documents from the collection and in the client side write a custom sort function that gives precedence to the user in concern. You could try that approach too since the `$ne` operator is not selective and will do a full collection scan. Anyway +1 for putting in the effort to understand.